# MS Access query problem

Tags: sql, inner-join, ms-access-2010

```
SELECT 
     tbl_vehicle_models.model_name AS Vehicle_Model,
     tbl_vehicle_models.manufacturer AS Manufacturer,
     tbl_jobs.vehicle_registration_number AS Registration_Number,
     tbl_customers.first_name + " " + tbl_customers.last_name AS Customer_Name,
     tbl_customers.address AS Address,
     tbl_customers.contact_no AS Contact_Number,
     tbl_jobs.cost_charged AS Cost,
     tbl_jobs.was_accident AS Was_Accident,
     tbl_jobs.was_towed AS Was_Towed,
     tbl_jobs.job_call_time AS Call_Time,
     tbl_jobs.job_arrival_time AS Arrival_Time,
     tbl_jobs.job_leaving_scene_time AS Leaving_Time,
     tbl_places.place_name AS Place
FROM 
    tbl_jobs
    INNER JOIN  tbl_vehicle_models
       ON  ( tbl_vehicle_models.ID = tbl_jobs.vehicle_model ) 
    INNER JOIN tbl_customers
       ON ( tbl_customers.ID =  tbl_jobs.customer_id )
    INNER JOIN tbl_places
       ON ( tbl_places.ID = tbl_jobs.job_place )
```

What's wrong with this query? I am getting error saying missing operator in query expression '( v.ID = j.vehicle_model )
    INNER JOIN tbl_customers c ON ( c.id =  j.customer_id )
    INNER JOIN  tbl_places p ON ( p.ID = j.job_place'

Edit: This solved my problem:

```
SELECT tbl_vehicle_models.model_name, tbl_vehicle_models.manufacturer, tbl_jobs.vehicle_registration_number, tbl_customers.first_name & " " & tbl_customers.last_name AS Expr1, tbl_customers.address, tbl_customers.contact_no, tbl_jobs.cost_charged, tbl_jobs.was_accident, tbl_jobs.was_towed, tbl_jobs.job_call_time, tbl_jobs.job_arrival_time, tbl_jobs.job_leaving_scene_time, tbl_places.place_name
FROM ((tbl_jobs INNER JOIN tbl_vehicle_models ON tbl_jobs.vehicle_model = tbl_vehicle_models.ID) INNER JOIN tbl_customers ON tbl_jobs.customer_id = tbl_customers.ID) INNER JOIN tbl_places ON tbl_jobs.job_place = tbl_places.ID;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
 SELECT tbl_vehicle_models.model_name, tbl_vehicle_models.manufacturer,
    tbl_jobs.vehicle_registration_number, tbl_customers.first_name & " " &
    tbl_customers.last_name AS Expr1, tbl_customers.address, tbl_customers.contact_no, 
    tbl_jobs.cost_charged, tbl_jobs.was_accident, tbl_jobs.was_towed, tbl_jobs.job_call_time,
    tbl_jobs.job_arrival_time, tbl_jobs.job_leaving_scene_time, tbl_places.place_name

    FROM ((tbl_jobs 
     INNER JOIN tbl_vehicle_models ON tbl_jobs.vehicle_model = tbl_vehicle_models.ID)
     INNER JOIN tbl_customers ON tbl_jobs.customer_id = tbl_customers.ID) 
     INNER JOIN tbl_places ON tbl_jobs.job_place = tbl_places.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `v.ID` and `j.vehicle_model` have the same data type?

Looks like `v.ID` is an integer and `j.vehicle_model` a string

I think this problem happens when you try to use operators with incompatible operand data types.

EDIT:
Then, try changing

```
c.first_name + " " + c.last_name
```

to

```
c.first_name & " " & c.last_name
```

I think that's a problem with this concatenation

Comment: Nopes I rechecked it, both are Integers

Comment: In Access you should use & to concatenate string. I have edited my answer

Comment: It doesn't work either. I removed all inner join statements and wrote FROM 
    tbl_jobs , tbl_vehicle_models , tbl_customers,  tbl_places and it works. But including inner join causes error.

Comment: I got it right! I had to nest my joins to make it work. I have edited my question.